# Cant call method from helper into model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wish to use this code but I am having difficulty getting it working. It is contained in a model:

```
def to_pdf
  title = @account.name
  subtitle = "Account Statement: #{@month_name} #{@year}"
  StatementPDF.new(title, subtitle, transactions).render
end
```

The transactions method is stored in a helper file (dont ask) but I cant seem to call it. Any suggestions.

```
def transactions(account_id, start, finish)
  return @transactions if @transactions 
  response = get_call('/Accounts/Statements/' + account_id.to_s + '/' + start + '/' + finish)
  response = JSON.parse(response.body)
  @transactions = response.map {|txn| Transaction.new(txn)}
end
```

I have had suggestions regarding placement of my transactions method but have to have it there for reasons above my paygrade. The strangest thing about this is that it worked at a point and when i reloaded the environment just to check everything was working as should be it stopped working again. Any suggestions?

Comment: Helpers are for the view layer; you'd need to include the helpers in the model. That's an awful place to put an HTTP call.

Comment: @Dave Newton Could you explain why its such a bad place to place an HTTP call as I'm relatively inexperienced. It was my boss who said to put it in helpers. What are the disadvantages and how would i go about switching this over to the model as I have tried that and it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Include helper inside your model ,it may work.

Answer (score 0):

(Moved to answer for readability, but it's more an extended comment.)

Helpers are for the view.

Making HTTP requests from the view layer is bad because (a) it puts too much logic into the view layer, and (b) it's counter-intuitive and could be misused, e.g., someone could accidentally (or purposefully) call it multiple times, potentially incurring the cost twice.

(Partially alleviated because of the sort-of caching, depending on access to `@transactions`.)

Something like this belongs in a utility class, called from the controller. (In general only the controller should generate data passed into the view.) That makes the controller easier to test because you can trivially mock/stub a top-level utility class method instead of having to use a fake web layer, mocking `get_call`, etc.

Unrelated, but Ruby favors string interpolation over concatenation, e.g.,

```
response = get_call("/Accounts/Statements/#{account_id.to_s}/#{start}/#{finish}")
```

I'm also not a fan of raw calls like this and prefer to see them behind some form of API mechanism, particularly if this is a pattern used throughout the app, something like:

```
def get_transactions_data(account_id, start, finish)
  response = get_call("/Accounts/Statements/#{account_id.to_s}/#{start}/#{finish}")
  JSON.parse(response.body)
end
```

(I might even create a URL builder as well, but I like really, really concise, communicative code.)

The step of transforming them into `Transaction` objects may or may not belong there as well, it depends on how your app is laid out, and how strongly your layers are separated.